# Java - Apache POI para Excel

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi

Preciso extrair as informações de um arquivo do Excel (xls) em formatação Biff4, e o Apache POI, apesar de ser ótimo para ler arquivos do Excel da versão 97-2003, não ajuda muito com estas versões mais antigas.

Que outra biblioteca posso usar para ler estes arquivos mais antigos?

Comment: Acho que vc pode considerar a solução postada aqui no [Slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336457/how-to-process-old-excel-xls-files-using-poi) mesmo. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336457/how-to-process-old-excel-xls-files-using-poi)

Comment: A solução apresentada naquela questão permanece muito complexa. O HSSF só serve para arquivos das versões 97-2003. O [OldExcelExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/OldExcelExtractor.html) ainda é complicado demais e me exigiria um baita malabarismo.